# Avoid line break in glossary but have it in section

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to do a manual linebreak in a section title but I do not want it to appear in the glossary (table of contents).

I'm using `\newline` to break the line in the section like:

```
  \chapter{Motivation zu \newline Computational Fluid Dynamics}
```

Because it does not fit on one line in the text but it fits on one line in the glossary so it does not need to break there.

Comment: `\chapter[Motivation zu Computational Fluid Dynamics]{Motivation zu \newline Computational Fluid Dynamics}`